# Should I use the readonly flag?

Tags: bash

Yesterday I've discovered that Bash provides a means to mark variables as read-only, using the readonly keyword:

```
readonly hello="hello"
hello="world" # error message, Bash refuses to reassign the variable
```

This seems like a nice feature, still, I've never seen this used in any Bash script. Is there any reason not to use this extensivly? Is it actually portable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readonly` is useful for some variables that are set by bash, for example `$UID` - non-readonly values like `$LOGNAME` and `$USER` are easy for the user to alter.
If you find `readonly` useful then use it!  Not many people use `readonly`, but don't let that bother you.  Downside - like other variable attributes, `readonly` attribute is not passed on with an exported variable, unless the child process is another bash.
One use of `readonly` is to apply it to a function.  That's not widely done, but it solves a support issue of (by mistake) having two functions of the same name, which can be an issue when using functions stored outside the script.
ksh also supports `readonly` (as an alias).

Answer (score -2):

value of 'readonly' variable cannot be modified further. Its as simple as a 'final' variable in java.

Comment: OP didn't ask what it does, but whether it's sensible to use it.